# Make spyder to use inprocess kernels

Tags: python, ipython, spyder, qtconsole

Is there a way to tell spyder (or maybe at least jupyter) to run inprocess kernels like you can do with qtconsole?
I am trying to use spyder from a different program and update namespace to work with large arrays (several GB +) and qtpy widgets.
I tried to modify the SpyderKernelManager base class but run into too many incompatibility issues.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) How do you connect to your in-process kernel from qtconsole?